# Jquery element replace problem

Tags: jquery

First I'm not sure this is the place to ask this question if not please direct it to its proper place.

The problem I am having is that I can get the first click function to work and have the html element change but I can't get the second click function to work and have the element change back. I was wondering how can I fix this problem?

Here is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.arrow').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('li').find('ol:first').fadeToggle('fast', 'linear');
        $(this).html('<span class="arrow-alt">&#8595;</span>');
    });

    $('.arrow-alt').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('li').find('ol:first').fadeToggle('fast', 'linear');
        $(this).html('<span class="arrow">&#8594;</span>');
    }); 

});
```

Comment: See: [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Jared, when you are using a [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event, it will work on the **existing** parts of the DOM.

When you are dynamically adding elements to the DOM and want to attach events to them, you have to use dynamic events like [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) if you are using jquery 1.7 or higher or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for previous versions.

Please no longer use the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method because it was **deprecated** on the 1.7 version of jquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ol>
    <span class="arrow">&#8594;</span>
</ol>
```

Note that if your html looks like the above markup, your code will produce a second span inside your first span instead of replacing the span. You can avoid this by changing the string parameter in the [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function and for example use [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

I think what you are looking for is something like this (ref use of [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) mentioned by JMax)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ol').on('click', '.arrow', function(event){
        $(this).closest('li').find('ol:first').fadeToggle('fast', 'linear');
        $(this).html('&#8595;');
        $(this).removeClass('arrow');
        $(this).addClass('arrow-alt');
    });

    $('ol').on('click', '.arrow-alt', function(event){
        $(this).closest('li').find('ol:first').fadeToggle('fast', 'linear');
        $(this).html('&#8594;');
        $(this).removeClass('arrow-alt');
        $(this).addClass('arrow');
    }); 
});
```